# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I am using Spark Structured Streaming to read messages from multiple topics in kafka.
I am facing below error:
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumerPool$PoolConfig.setMinEvictableIdleTime(Ljava/time/Duration;)V**

Below are my maven dependencies I am using,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>untitled</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>A Camel Scala Route</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- Camel BOM -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.4</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-scala</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- scala -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang.modules</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-xml_2.13</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--spark-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--spark Streaming kafka-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--kafka-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--jackson-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>

    <plugins>

      <!-- the Maven compiler plugin will compile Java source files -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- the Maven Scala plugin will compile Scala source files -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- configure the eclipse plugin to generate eclipse project descriptors for a Scala project -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <configuration>
          <projectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
            <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
          </projectnatures>
          <buildcommands>
            <buildcommand>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
          </buildcommands>
          <classpathContainers>
            <classpathContainer>org.scala-ide.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
          </classpathContainers>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-library</exclude>
            <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-compiler</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <sourceIncludes>
            <sourceInclude>**/*.scala</sourceInclude>
            <sourceInclude>**/*.java</sourceInclude>
          </sourceIncludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- allows the route to be run via 'mvn exec:java' -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>org.example.MyRouteMain</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Scala Version: `2.13.8`
Spark Version: `3.3.0`

This my Code snippet to read from Kafka topics:

```
object consumerMain {

val log : Logger = Logger.getLogger(controller.driver.getClass)

val config: Map[String, String]=Map[String,String](
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers" -> bootstrapServer,
    "startingOffsets" -> "earliest",
    "kafka.security.protocol" -> security_protocol,
    "kafka.ssl.truststore.location" -> truststore_location,
    "kafka.ssl.truststore.password" -> password,
    "kafka.ssl.keystore.location" -> keystore_location,
    "kafka.ssl.keystore.password" -> password,
    "kafka.ssl.key.password"-> password,
    "kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm"-> ""
  )

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit ={

    log.info("SPARKSESSION CREATED!!!")
      val spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("kafka-sample-consumer")
        .master("local")
        .getOrCreate()

    log.info("READING MESSAGES FROM KAFKA!!!")
      val kafkaMsg = spark
        .readStream
        .format("Kafka")
        .options(config)
        .option("kafka.group.id", group_id)
        .option("subscribe", "sample_topic_T")
        .load()

    kafkaMsg.printSchema()

    kafkaMsg.writeStream
      .format("console")
      //.outputMode("append")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()


  }
}
```

Below, I am able to see the kafka proeprties I have set in the logs printed on the console:

```
[                          main] StateStoreCoordinatorRef       INFO  Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
[                          main] ContextHandler                 INFO  Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6e00837f{/StreamingQuery,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
[                          main] ContextHandler                 INFO  Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6a5dd083{/StreamingQuery/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
[                          main] ContextHandler                 INFO  Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1e6bd263{/StreamingQuery/statistics,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
[                          main] ContextHandler                 INFO  Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@635ff2a5{/StreamingQuery/statistics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
[                          main] ContextHandler                 INFO  Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@62735b13{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
[                          main] ResolveWriteToStream           WARN  Temporary checkpoint location created which is deleted normally when the query didn't fail: C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\temporary-c2ca1d2c-2c8d-4961-a1bd-1881bc00e0bb. If it's required to delete it under any circumstances, please set spark.sql.streaming.forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation to true. Important to know deleting temp checkpoint folder is best effort.
[                          main] ResolveWriteToStream           INFO  Checkpoint root C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\temporary-c2ca1d2c-2c8d-4961-a1bd-1881bc00e0bb resolved to file:/C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Temp/temporary-c2ca1d2c-2c8d-4961-a1bd-1881bc00e0bb.
[                          main] ResolveWriteToStream           WARN  spark.sql.adaptive.enabled is not supported in streaming DataFrames/Datasets and will be disabled.
[                          main] CheckpointFileManager          INFO  Writing atomically to file:/C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Temp/temporary-c2ca1d2c-2c8d-4961-a1bd-1881bc00e0bb/metadata using temp file file:/C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Temp/temporary-c2ca1d2c-2c8d-4961-a1bd-1881bc00e0bb/.metadata.c2b5aa2a-2a86-4931-a4f0-bbdaae8c3d5f.tmp
[                          main] CheckpointFileManager          INFO  Renamed temp file file:/C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Temp/temporary-c2ca1d2c-2c8d-4961-a1bd-1881bc00e0bb/.metadata.c2b5aa2a-2a86-4931-a4f0-bbdaae8c3d5f.tmp to file:/C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Temp/temporary-c2ca1d2c-2c8d-4961-a1bd-1881bc00e0bb/metadata
[                          main] MicroBatchExecution            INFO  Starting [id = 54eadb58-a957-4f8d-b67e-24ef6717482c, runId = ceb06ba5-1ce6-4ccd-bfe9-b4e24fd497a6]. Use file:/C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Temp/temporary-c2ca1d2c-2c8d-4961-a1bd-1881bc00e0bb to store the query checkpoint.
[5-1ce6-4ccd-bfe9-b4e24fd497a6]] MicroBatchExecution            INFO  Reading table [org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaTable@5efc8880] from DataSourceV2 named 'Kafka' [org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider@2703aebd]
[5-1ce6-4ccd-bfe9-b4e24fd497a6]] KafkaSourceProvider            WARN  Kafka option 'kafka.group.id' has been set on this query, it is
 not recommended to set this option. This option is unsafe to use since multiple concurrent
 queries or sources using the same group id will interfere with each other as they are part
 of the same consumer group. Restarted queries may also suffer interference from the
 previous run having the same group id. The user should have only one query per group id,
 and/or set the option 'kafka.session.timeout.ms' to be very small so that the Kafka
 consumers from the previous query are marked dead by the Kafka group coordinator before the
 restarted query starts running.
    
[5-1ce6-4ccd-bfe9-b4e24fd497a6]] MicroBatchExecution            INFO  Starting new streaming query.
[5-1ce6-4ccd-bfe9-b4e24fd497a6]] MicroBatchExecution            INFO  Stream started from {}
[5-1ce6-4ccd-bfe9-b4e24fd497a6]] ConsumerConfig                 INFO  ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092, localhost: 9093]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = kafka-message-test-group
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 1
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = 
    ssl.key.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = src/main/resources/consumer_inlet/keystore.jks
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = src/main/resources/consumer_inlet/truststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

The following error I am getting while running the consumerMain:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Writing job aborted
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 54eadb58-a957-4f8d-b67e-24ef6717482c, runId = ceb06ba5-1ce6-4ccd-bfe9-b4e24fd497a6]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[sample_topic_T]]: {"clinical_sample_T":{"0":155283144,"1":155233229}}}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
WriteToMicroBatchDataSource org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ConsoleTable$@4f9c824, 54eadb58-a957-4f8d-b67e-24ef6717482c, Append
+- StreamingDataSourceV2Relation [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13], org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaScan@135a05da, KafkaV2[Subscribe[sample_topic_T]]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:208)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.writingJobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:749)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collect$1(Dataset.scala:3120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3858)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:510)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3856)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3856)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:3120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$17(MicroBatchExecution.scala:663)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:658)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:658)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:255)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:307)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:285)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (LHTU05CG050CC8Q.ms.ds.uhc.com executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumerPool$PoolConfig.setMinEvictableIdleTime(Ljava/time/Duration;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumerPool$PoolConfig.init(InternalKafkaConsumerPool.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumerPool$PoolConfig.<init>(InternalKafkaConsumerPool.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumerPool.<init>(InternalKafkaConsumerPool.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer$.<clinit>(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:637)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaBatchPartitionReader.<init>(KafkaBatchPartitionReader.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaBatchReaderFactory$.createReader(KafkaBatchPartitionReader.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.advanceToNextIter(DataSourceRDD.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.hasNext(Iterator.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:435)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1538)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:480)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:377)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumerPool$PoolConfig.setMinEvictableIdleTime(Ljava/time/Duration;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumerPool$PoolConfig.init(InternalKafkaConsumerPool.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumerPool$PoolConfig.<init>(InternalKafkaConsumerPool.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumerPool.<init>(InternalKafkaConsumerPool.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer$.<clinit>(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:637)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaBatchPartitionReader.<init>(KafkaBatchPartitionReader.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaBatchReaderFactory$.createReader(KafkaBatchPartitionReader.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.advanceToNextIter(DataSourceRDD.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.hasNext(Iterator.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:435)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1538)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:480)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

**I am running this in intellij**

Comment: You're not showing your maven plugins. Did you create an uber jar? What command are you using to run the code? Ideally, it should run in Intellij, but you might have to use `spark-submit`

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer , I have added the Pom file with the plugins I am using,  I am not using spark-submit as I am running this in intellij, I have already implemented kafka connectivity using `consumer.poll()` method in intellij, but using structured streaming I am facing this error. I don't know If I am missing something.

Comment: The class from your error should be part of your `spark-sql-kafka-0-10` dependency. I will try to reproduce locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded the version of spark from 3.3.0 to 3.2.2 with the Scala version 2.13.8 remaining the same. For me, it seems the Scala version 2.13 was not compatible with Spark version 3.3.0 . For now I am able to write the Avro data to a file.

**And Thanks to @OneCricketeer for your help and support so far!**

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same issue with Spark 3.3.0. I did some deep dive and finally found out the root cause: Spark 3.3.0 has built-in dependency on commons-pools v.1.5.4 (commons-pool-1.5.4.jar) while this structure streaming library relies on v2.11.1 which replaced `setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis` with `setMinEvictableIdleTime`. Thus the resolution is to add commons-pool2-2.11.1.jar to your Spark jars folder. This jar can be downloaded from Maven central https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-pool2/2.11.1/commons-pool2-2.11.1.jar.

I've documented the details on the page if you want to learn more:
https://kontext.tech/article/1178/javalangnosuchmethoderror-poolconfigsetminevictableidletime

Comment: This solution worked for me with apache spark 3.3.1. I also checked spark 3.5.0 installable and there too commons-pool-1.5.4.jar is present. Is this not a bug with spark? I was expecting latest release to have commons-pool2-2.11.1.jar which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the error (using latest IntelliJ Ultimate), but here's the POM and code

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>cricket.jomoore</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SOReady4Spark</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

        <scala.compat.version>2.13</scala.compat.version>
        <scala.version>${scala.compat.version}.8</scala.version>

        <spark.version>3.3.0</spark.version>

        <spec2.version>4.2.0</spec2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.7.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`<scope>provided</scope>` tags are needed for when you actually deploy Spark code to a real Spark cluster. And for that, you also need to configure IntelliJ run config. [image]

```
package cricketeer.one;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetResetStrategy
import org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, DataTypes}
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

object KafkaTest extends App {

  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

  /**
   * For testing output to a console.
   *
   * @param df A Streaming DataFrame
   * @return A DataStreamWriter
   */
  private def streamToConsole(df: sql.DataFrame) = {
    df.writeStream.outputMode(OutputMode.Append()).format("console")
  }

  private def getKafkaDf(spark: SparkSession, bootstrap: String, topicPattern: String, offsetResetStrategy: OffsetResetStrategy = OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST) = {
    spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap)
      .option("subscribe", topicPattern)
      .option("startingOffsets", offsetResetStrategy.toString.toLowerCase())
      .load()
  }

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Kafka Test")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._

  val kafkaBootstrap = "localhost:9092"

  val df = getKafkaDf(spark, kafkaBootstrap, "input-topic")
  streamToConsole(
    df.select($"value".cast(DataTypes.StringType))
  ).start().awaitTermination()
}
```

- src/main/resources/log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher" level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, I am using kafka.group.id, with spark structured streaming, I am not sure if this has anything to do with the error I am getting.

Comment: No, it does not. I only exclude it for my code so that I can re-run it and get the same data from the beginning of the topic for testing purposes.

Comment: Hi @Onecricketeer, thanks for your help. I checked one of your previous posts regarding deserializing Avro Data. I am using Abris for deserializing Avro but getting the following error: ```Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject not found.; error code: 40401```

Comment: Upgrade the confluent avro serializer dependency version and it'll tell you what subject was not able to be found. Then debug from there.